# Generic logic for sorting of different types

Tags: java, sorting, generics, collections

I have some class hierarchy for DTO objects. Lets say the base abstract class is AbstractObject and this is empty class. The class Product extends AbstractObject and has some properties, setters, getters.
I have some logic responsible for sorting the Product objects:

```
public enum ProductComparator implements Comparator<Product>  {
    ROK_SORT_ASC {
        @Override
        public int compare(Product u1, Product u2) {
            return ObjectUtils.compare(u1.getRok(), u2.getRok());
        }
    },
    ROK_SORT_DESC {
        @Override
        public int compare(Product u1, Product u2) {
            return -ObjectUtils.compare(u1.getRok(), u2.getRok());
        }
    },
    NAME_DESC {
        @Override
        public int compare(Product u1, Product u2) {
            return -(ObjectUtils.compare(u1.getFlDyn(), (u2.getFlDyn())));
        }
    };

    public static Comparator<Product> doCompare(final Comparator<Product> other) {
        return new Comparator<Product>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Product u1, Product u2) {
                return other.compare(u1, u2);
            }
        };
    }

    public static Comparator<Product> getComparator(final List<ProductComparator> sortOptions) {
        if(sortOptions == null ){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null list passed to comparator");
        }

        return new Comparator<Product>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Product u1, Product u2) {
            for (ProductComparator option : sortOptions) {
                int result = option.compare(u1, u2);
                if (result != 0) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    };
}
}
```

This is simple composite with comparators.

Now, I want to make some methods generic, so it will be able to create a list as follows:

```
    List<AbstractObject> objectsList = new ArrayList<AbstractObject>();
    objectsList.add(new Product("...", "...."));
    objectsList.add(new Product("...", "...."));
```

and invoke sort method:

```
    List<ProductComparator> comparators = new ArrayList<ProductComparator>();
    comparators.add(ProductComparator.ROK_SORT_ASC);

    Collections.sort(objectsList, ProductComparator.doCompare(ProductComparator.getComparator(comparators)));
```

Now, because of lack of the generic methods it is not possible, unfortunately I am not able do this in this case. There will be many objects extending AbstractObjects and I want to automatize some processes.
I am running with Java 1.6. Casting of objects is prohibited.

Comment: How do you expect to sort list of unknown objects with product comparator?